# How to remove Delta bathtub handle?

Tags: bathtub

I am at my breaking point on how to take this shower handle off. It's a Delta and I need to replace some o-rings in it to stop my leaking faucet. I don't seem to see a set screw anywhere on this thing at all. I took off the backing plate to still find nothing.

How do I take this thing off so I can access the inside?

It's a Delta Monitor and it says 13/14 Multichoice on it.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 11):

Using a flat plastic tool (like a putty knife), pop off the small cap at the end of the lever (handle). Then use an Allen wrench or well-fitting screwdriver, as appropriate, to loosen the attachment screw, which may act as a set screw for the lever base.